# Include variables into a class in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, class, connection

I'am trying to write a **function** that includes any variable into a classs. For example:

My function:
add_action($VARS_ARRAY);

This function should include $VARS_ARRAY into A class.

How can I do it in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need a function for this, you can just add a value directly.

```
$a = new A();
$a->vars_array = $VARS_ARRAY;
```